# How to export to .XLS from a tab-separated .CSV (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, csv

I'm trying to use Rails' CSV class to export data to a .XLS file. Some of this data contains text with commas, so I put the following arguments in my csv generator:

```
CSV.generate(col_sep: "\t", row_sep: "\n") do |csv|...
```

This generates the format:

```
Date,\tAccount,\tReference,\tDetails,\tGross,\tTax,\tNet
```

But when I try to export it to .XLS:

```
send_data xls_data, :filename => "#{filename}.xls", :type => "application/vnd.ms-excel", :disposition => "attachment"
```

the file I open looks like this:

[image: broken-spreadsheet]

As you can see, the tabs are being put in the cells, and the cells are being divided by commas found in the numbers.

How do I get the xls to separate cells by tabs?

Note: I'm using Mac Numbers to view the sheets, I don't have access to Excel so I'm not sure what they look like there.

Comment: CSV stands for **Comma**-Separated Values. Using tabs will likely be quite tricky. Can you reformat your numbers so they don't have the formatting commas in them?

Comment: I am quite sure that Excel will be able to deal with tabs as well. It guesses the separator and lets you correct the guess.

Comment: Eventually I got it working by using comma separators—not tabs. It works, but is sub-optimal because there might be commas in the data...

Comment: How do you generate xls_data in your call to send_data?

Comment: Date,\tAccount,\tReference,\tDetails,\tGross,\tTax,\tNet

this looks wrong. you should either use comma or tab, not both. can you show what you push to csv variable?